# Adding labels for radio-boxes in Magento

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, magento

Trying to use label for each radio-box(to customise them with css3), but there is javascript preventing the labels to work as they should. When I click on a label, the radio-box gets focused but not checked.

If you click straight on the radio-box, it validates and adds a class *.validation-passed* to the input. Maybe I need to make a validation for the label aswell?

Anyone faced this before and could help out to make it work?

```
<table class="data-table review-summary-table" id="product-review-table">
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($this->getRatings() as $_rating): ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">
                <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>
            </td>
            <?php foreach ($_rating->getOptions() as $_option): ?>
            <td class="value">
                <label for="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?php echo $_option->getValue() ?>">
                    <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?> <?php echo $_option->getValue() ?>
                </label>
                <input type="radio" name="ratings[<?php echo $_rating->getId() ?>]" id="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?php echo $_option->getValue() ?>" value="<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>" class="radio" />
            </td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="validate_rating" class="validate-rating" value="" />
<script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-review-table')</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that all of radio boxes have different names.
If you want collate it to 1 group you should use same names for all radio buttons.

```
name="ratings"
```

Comment: Yes. Try use same names. Also why you use value for radio button? It can be checked or unchecked. Only 2 values